# WebStorm 2020.2.2 can't use Zsh

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, terminal, webstorm, zsh

I'm using WebStorm 2020.2.2, zsh with oh-my-zsh, on Pop!_OS 20.04 (a distro based on Ubuntu). I have set the usual zsh usage for GNOME Terminal and it worked fine. `echo $SHELL` returns `/usr/bin/zsh`.

On WebStorm, I have tried to configure it to use `/bin/zsh` and `/usr/bin/zsh` but I can't run the terminal using built-in terminal tool window (little window on the bottom, key: alt-F12). It shows errors like this:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [/bin/zsh, -i] in /home/dep/Development/proj/foodcrate/kitchen


See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in File Manager) for the details.
```

and this error on the log file:

```
2020-09-19 16:55:41,596 [ 488848]   INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start [/bin/zsh, -i] in /home/dep/Development/proj/foodcrate/kitchen
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:202)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner.lambda$openSessionInDirectory$4(AbstractTerminalRunner.java:211)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:268)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown reason
    at com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.execInPty(UnixPtyProcess.java:272)
    at com.pty4j.unix.UnixPtyProcess.<init>(UnixPtyProcess.java:86)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:111)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:78)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:190)
    ... 13 more
```

Same thing happened on my Android Studio 4.0.1, which I think would be the same issue since both are Intellij-based IDE (or something like it).

What could be done to fix this? It'll be annoying to have to open a separate terminal window. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error has been reported at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247488. Please attach idea.log after disabling plugins in the mentioned issue and perform the steps mentioned by Arine Efremova.

Comment: Unfortunately, the underlying reason of failure is not clear enough.
Such errors will be reported with more information in future (please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217416). How did you install the IDE? Please make sure to use one of the officially recommended options https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/installation-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (with phpStorm)

here is what fixed it for me:

1. uninstall phpstorm via pop os store
2. download and install the jetbrains installer
3. re-install webstorm via the installer

I did this, and everything was all better

Comment: After hours of trying to fix this issue, this was the only solution that worked.